# Mobile Center Build Issue

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I've started to use Visual Studio Mobile Center which seems to be a very good tools for my development lifecycle. I am actually working on a Xamarin Forms project and am using Github as Source Control.

Unfortunately I am unable to build my project on Mobile Center. My project is referencing many other projects hosted on GitHub and Mobile Center cannot get those references. I like to separate my projects when I work, such as Test.FrontEnd, Test.BackEnd, Test.API...

How can I build my project on Mobile Center and get the reference of all my other projects? Because I don't want to merge them all together

Comment: If you have everything in GitHub and only GitHub, it should work.

Comment: What kind of references does your project have to those hosted on GitHub? If it's submodules, you might want to look at this [piece in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/build/faq#are-git-submodules-supported).

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only thing you can do is merge them into one. Other scenarios are not supported right now in Mobile Center.

An alternative could be to use the full-featured big brother Visual Studio Team Services. But I'm not either sure you can do it in there. Usually people put their code belonging to one project at least in the same repo.